# wordpress menu and viewing capability

Tags: php, wordpress

I have spent hours looking for a way to make a custom admin menu visable to admins and a custom user role I made called moderators. The menu only appears for admins and not the moderators. How can I make it display for both user types?

**functions.php**

```
add_role( 'moderator', 'Moderator', array(
        'read' => true,
        'add_users'
    ));

    add_action('admin_menu', 'staff_menu');

    function staff_menu() {
       add_menu_page('Staff Menu: Options', 'Staff Menu', 'add_users', 'staff', 'staff_page', "favicon.ico", 3);
    }

    function staff_page(){
       echo "Staff Page Test will have options here";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to give the `add_users` a value of `true`. The [docs for `add_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) show that you need to pass a value, probably a boolean.

```
add_role( 'moderator', 'Moderator', array(
        'read' => true,
        'add_users' => true
    ));
```

---

**Update:** Check to see if the *admin* role still has the `add_users` capability.

```
$admin_role = get_role('admin');
var_dump($admin_role->has_cap('add_users'));
```

Comment: only gives access to admin and no one else

Comment: @Mr.1.0 what happens if you delete the role and rerun the function. WordPress might not find the changes because the role already exists.

Comment: if i remove the role and return function only it appears for moderator and not for admin now lol

Comment: @Mr.1.0 that's really strange. I'm not sure caused that. I've done a few searches and can't find a solution.

Comment: @Mr.1.0 see my update, did you accidentally remove the `add_users` capability from the admin role too?

Comment: do i have to keep the add_role( 'moderator', 'Moderator',..... code in the functions.php file or can i remove it since its already in the database? and i change add_users to manage_options and it worked.

Comment: @Mr.1.0 If you've already run the function in your production database, then you can go ahead and remove it. Although, it would probably be best in a plugin so it will still be there when you change the theme. Also, it's strange that `add_users` conflicted with the admin role.